# how to outline a font character in prawn / ruby (pdf)

Tags: ruby, prawn

I would like to draw a character (TTF) as vector and wondering how to perhaps draw the outline of the character. It appears that characters are "filled" with color suggesting the possibility to outline. I've tried stroke_color to no avail. I am using ruby and prawn to render in pdf.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've been needing this feature myself, so I just added it to prawn. With the caveat that the API may change slightly after feature review from the other devs, here's how it works:

```
Prawn::Document.generate "rendering_mode.pdf" do |pdf|
  pdf.fill_color "00ff00"
  pdf.stroke_color "0000ff"

  pdf.text("Inline mode", :mode => 1, :size => 40)
end
```

For a list of valid values to mode, check the code docs for the text_rendering_mode method.

If you want to cherry pick the changes, the specific commit that adds support is at [here](http://github.com/sandal/prawn/commit/e6177bb1555ef24e9046215139fc22d54c12d872).

Comment: Thanks much! how to I replace my current prawn version with the latest which includes your code?

Comment: If I understand correctly, this still renders the shape as text though, right? Is there any way to stroke or fill some text as just a "shape"?